# how to use iterable with inheritence

Tags: java, inheritance, iterator, wildcard, iterable

I have two classes named `Cards` and `ActionCard` that implement `ICards` and `ICard` respectively, which are being contained in two different modules - module `A` contains the `Cards` and `ActionCard` classes and depends on module `B`, which contains the `ICards` and `ICard` interfaces.

I'm trying to iterate over the `Cards` class that contains a `List` of `ActionCard` in module `A`, and iterate over `ICards` interface in module `B`.

I tried to define the `Cards` class as `Iterable<ActionCard>` with the method `Iterator<ActionCard> iterator()`, but since `ActionCard` is not known in module `B`, I wanted to define `ICards` as `Iterable<ICard>`, which means the method `iterator()` in `Cards` couldn't return `Iterator<ActionCard>` because it's a whole different type from `Iterator<ICard>` (and I don't want to change to `ICard` in module `A` since I need to work with the `ActionCard`).

I tried using wildcard to define `Iterable<? extends ICard>` in the `Cards` class and it gives an error:

> No wildcard expected

and when I try to define the method `Iterator<? extends ICard> iterator(`) in that class it gives an error:

> iterator() in Cards clashes with iterator() in java.lang.iterable; attempting to use incompatible return type.

```
//Module A:
public class Cards implements ICards, Iterable<? extends ICard> {

    private List<ActionCard> m_Cards = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends ICard> iterator(){        
        return m_Cards.iterator();
    }
}

public class ActionCard implements ICard {
   //...some methods
}

//Module B:
public interface ICards extends Iterable<? extends ICard> {
   //...some methods
}

public interface ICard {
   //...some methods
}
```

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't understand why are you creating that `Cards` wrapper for ArrayList. Why don't you simply use `ArrayList<ICard>` or `ArrayList<? extends ICard>`?

Comment: Maybe it wasnt clear, but Cards has alot of more methods and members which are not relevant to my question, hence its a class.

Comment: But it still just wraps the functionality of an ArrayList. Maybe it would be easier to have `Cards extends ArrayList<? extends ICard>`. This way you won't have to reimplement methods like `iterator()` and possibly some others which you use, but are available in ArrayList implementation.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public interface ICards<T> extends Iterable<T> {
  // ..some methods
}
```

and

```
public class Cards implements ICards<ActionCard> {

    private List<ActionCard> m_Cards = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Iterator<ActionCard> iterator()
    {        
        return m_Cards.iterator();
    }
}
```

Since your `Cards` class always creates a `List` of `ActionCard` and iterates over that `List`, it makes sense to define it to implement `ICards<ActionCard>`.

And since `Cards` implements `ICards`, which extends `Iterable`, you don't have to explicitly state that `Cards` implements `Iterable`.

Comment: first of all thanks, it works. second - since ive wanted to iterate over a collection of objects that implement ICard, ive used constrains and defnied it as: ```public interface ICards<T extends ICard> extends Iterable<T> {
  // ..some methods
}```